# botframework error GraphException

Tags: azure, botframework

I was creating a bot in azure, but when I try to generate a password shows me a error in the creation:

> "Microsoft.AppRegPortal.Providers.Graph.GraphException"

I dont know if it is my fault or not.

[image]

Comment: This underlying issue has been identified and is being addressed by the team.  We apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

New password generation is currently broken.  However, I just learned from someone on https://gitter.im/Microsoft/BotBuilder , there is a way to retrieve the initially generated appid and password:

MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword can be found by navigating to the ResourceGroup for the Bot Registration, choosing “Deployments”, then the specific deployment for the bot.

**MicrosoftAppId=APPID**

**MicrosoftAppPassword=APPSECRET**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue is very specific to the Applications created internally as a part of bot creation process using Azure Portal. Because creating new Application manually in "apps.dev.microsoft.com" has no such issues.

Considering this the only option feasible right now is to create "Web App Bot" and refer the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword from "App Settings" of App Service Settings. Then update this new ID and Secret in messaging endpoint service web.config file.